# How to stop Power BI Cards from refreshing in order to export to PDF?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Power BI Desktop file with 6 tabs. Each tab is a collection of Card visuals. When I switch between tabs, the cards take a second to refresh. When I try to export as PDF, the same happens, and the final PDF file ends up with white space where the data from the cards should be.

A way to bypass this is to have a separate file for each tab, but it's very inefficient. Is there a way for the cards to not update when I switch tabs?

Comment: Are you using Import or Direct query data for the cards? If Direct query, Import may yield better results.

Comment: I am connecting the Power BI file to Salesforce. The data is already imported and modeled in Power BI. Is there a way to optimize that connection? Although I don't think the problem is tied to that connection.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a limitation of the Card visualization. I was able to "work" around it by publishing the file. On the web view the **Publish to PDF** option does the rendering in the background, which bypasses the limitation of the card as it does not have to switch tabs for rendering.